# Child view controller's view ignores Auto Layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I would like to add child view controller to `UINavigationController's` view. I have hierarchy like this
`NavigationController` -> View(`drawer`) -> View(`contentContainer`) -> child view controller should be pinned to the contentContainer

But for some reason it ignores the constraints and I get weird results. Please see the screenshot, `drawer` is green, `contentContainer` is yellow and the child controller is placed almost outside of the screen and has frame with 0 height.

[image]

The critical code is inside the `drawerContentController` `didSet` and `setupView` method. Please note that I'm using SnapKit for constraints but the same problem was happening by setting the `NSLayoutConstraints` traditionally

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    private var drawerHeightConstraint: Constraint!
    
    fileprivate lazy var drawer = UIView()
    private lazy var contentContainer = UIView()
    var drawerContentController: UIViewController? {
        didSet {
            guard let new = drawerContentController else {
                oldValue?.removeFromParent(animated: true)
                return
            }
            if let old = oldValue {
                old.removeFromParent(animated: true) { _ in
                    self.add(child: new, superview: self.contentContainer, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            } else {
                add(child: new, superview: contentContainer, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(drawer)
        drawer.backgroundColor = .green
        drawer.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.bottom.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            drawerHeightConstraint = make.height.equalTo(360).constraint
        }
        
        let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .default)
        let visualView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
        drawer.addSubview(visualView)
        visualView.pinToSuperView()
        
        contentContainer.backgroundColor = .yellow
        drawer.addSubview(contentContainer)
        contentContainer.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(drawer.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
        }
    }

    func add(child controller: UIViewController, superview: UIView? = nil, animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        
        controller.willMove(toParent: self)
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.alpha = 0
        (superview ?? view).addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.view.pinToSuperView()
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animated ? 0.3 : 0, animations: {
            controller.view.alpha = 1
        }) { finished in
            controller.didMove(toParent: self)
            completion?(finished)
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func pinToSuperView() {
        snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

When I add a simple UIView to the contentContainer it works as expected

```
var drawerContentController: UIViewController? {
    didSet {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .purple
        contentContainer.addSubview(v)
        v.pinToSuperView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: See the exclamation marks? Those are auto layout mistakes you are making. You need to see what they are.

Comment: It just said that size is ambiguous for the view. Do you see that on second screenshot there is tableview visible under the colored views? Whereas on the first there there is no controller at all, it seems that UINavigationController does not like adding child controllers to it. I will embeed the navigation controller in other controller and add the child view to the embeeding controller

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "just". The ambiguity _is_ the reason for the problem you're having.

Comment: It is not, as I said in the post a simple UIView when added and positioned using the same constraints works properly. UINavigationController doesn't allow adding child view controllers as it seems

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I "solved" the issue.

It seems that `UINavigationController` does not like having child view controllers added to it. As seen on the screenshots, when child controller is added the entire view hierarchy of navigation controller is broken. On the second screenshot, the table view controller (white view) is displayed correctly, but in the first case it is not even in the view hierarchy!

So the moral is, try to not add child view controllers directly to `UINavigationController`, in the end it is not a normal `UIViewController` and doesn't even have a normal `UIView`. I have added another `UIViewController` to act as a container for `UINavigationController` and added the child controller to it. It now works as expected.

Comment: A UINavigationController does have a "normal UIView". The problem here is merely that you have not allowed for the fact that a UINavigationController _already_ has children, which it treats in the special way appropriate to a navigation controller: they are the view controllers pushed onto its stack, plain and simple.